# HTML Change login label to username after login

Tags: php

> Before
>   [image: before log in]
>
> After
>   [image]

I want to know how to do this after i login successfully.Just give me some idea to start with will do.?

Here is my code for checklogin.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 define("DB_HOST","localhost");
 define("DB_NAME","user_database");
 define("DB_USER","root");
 define("DB_PASSWORD","");

 mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) 
or die("Failed to connect to the database");

 $myusername=$_POST["myusername"];
 $mypassword=$_POST["mypassword"];
 $myencryptedpassword=md5($mypassword); 
 $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' AND      password='$myencryptedpassword'";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count==1){
$_SESSION['is_logged']=true;
$_SESSION['username']=$myusername;
echo "Login Successful. Welcome ".$myusername;
sleep(2);
header("refresh:1;url=onlinestore.html");
    }
  else{
echo "Wrong Username or Password.Please try again. ";
sleep(2);
header("refresh:2;url=login.html");}
  ?>
```

Here is my code for onlinestore.html

```
<body>

        <li class='active' style='float:right;'><a href='registerform.html'><span  id='register'>Login/Register</span></a></li>;
```

> This is the part in the body that i want to change. I want it to change from Login/Register to the username after login successful.

Comment: like raheel said something like a session or cookie

Comment: please read a lot about `SQL INJECTION`. Also do some reading on `PDO_MYSQL` instead of `mysql_*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a simple condition

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in']){
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}else{
    echo 'Please login';
}
```

When your login condition gets true set some session data or cookie data then use a condition to display content based on session or cookie

Comment: this should be write inside my homepage.html?

Comment: where did the `session_start();` go?

Comment: this should be written in your header page if you are including header in every page. Else you need to write it to every page

Comment: Make sure that you set `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` when logging in though :P Sounds stupid, but I think it might come handy as it seems you don't have alot of knowledge about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a if condition.

inside the html code but before the label is defined.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['is_logged'])
    echo "<label>$_SESSION['username']</label>";
 else
    echo "<label>Please login</label>";

?>
```

Comment: what is the output for $_SESSION['is_logged'] ? make sure its true.

Comment: i had done edited and posted my code there,i dont know where to start with after i make $_SESSION['is_logged']=true;

Comment: can you please help me?i really need help here