# HTML PHP Display username after success login

Tags: php, html

I have a `<div>` inside my onlinestore.html file which is my menu that contain of Login/Register. What I want is after the success login, the `<div>` for login/register change to the username. What i'hv done wont display the expected output that i want.So is there something wrong about my code?

Here is what I've done:

onlinestore.html

```
<li class='active' style='float:right;'>
  <?php 
  session_start();
    if($_SESSION['logged']==true){ 
        echo $_SESSION["username"];
        echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
        }
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false) 
        echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
    ?>
```

Here is another file
checklogin.php:

```
if($count==1){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['logged']=true;
  $_SESSION ['username']=$myusername;
  header("refresh:1;url=onlinestore.html");
  }
else{
   $_SESSION['logged']=false;
   header("refresh:2;url=login.html");}
```

Here is the expected output:

> Before Login
>   [image]
>
> After Login
>   [image]
>
> Here is what i get with the code above:
>   [image: My code wont work]

Comment: Yeah you ask for something that you already done.

Comment: the code i show above is not working like the expected output.Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: You should use the $_SESSION["username"] and put it in that div/span or whatever container that you are using.

Comment: As I said in the other question, you need to say WHAT doesn't work. You get a blank page? User never seems to be logged in? etc

Comment: where is the login script? where you set the $_SESSION attributes.

Comment: @James i'hv edit the question and show the screenshot of the error i get

Comment: Looks like you're not setting the $_SESSION['username'] properly (or at all). Can you `var_dump($_SESSION['username'])` and see the real output? If it's null, that's your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Change login label to username after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611949/html-change-login-label-to-username-after-login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you need to rename your `onlinestore.html` and `login.html` to be .php files so the PHP will work in them, or use the addtype option in your htaccess file.

In your `onlinestore.html` do this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Right at the top of your script
?>

<li class='active' style='float:right;'>
  <?php 
  if($_SESSION['logged']==true)
    { 
      echo $_SESSION["username"];
      echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
    }
  elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false)
    {
      echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
    }
  ?>
```

In your `checklogin.php` do this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Right at the top of your script
?>

if($count==1)
  {
    $_SESSION['logged']=true;
    $_SESSION['username']=$myusername;
    header("Location: onlinestore.html");
    exit();
  }
else
  {
     $_SESSION['logged']=false;
     header("Location: login.html");
     exit();
  }
```

If the above doesn't work then please tell me what happens.
Do you have html files set to parse PHP code?
Or a htaccess file with:
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html`
?

### EDIT

Try this for debugging:

In your `checklogin.php` do this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Right at the top of your script
?>

if($count==1)
  {
    $_SESSION['logged']=true;
    $_SESSION['username']=$myusername;
    echo "Login worked";
    exit();
  }
else
  {
     $_SESSION['logged']=false;
     echo "Login failed";
     exit();
  }
```

This will show you if login is working. If it's not and you get "login failed" then that is why you get the "Login/Register" link on your page.

If it shows "Login worked" then set the code back to how it was and then on your `onlinestore.html` page, do this at the top of the file:

```
echo "This is working";
exit();
```

What happens? Do you get the message "This is working" on the page and nothing else?

Comment: it doesn't work,it still show me the same output that i show above

Comment: Again, what doesn't work? The image you show has "Login/Register" and looks like a link, which looks to me like the code in `onlinestore.html` is going to the else. I'll edit my answer with some things to try

Comment: the problem is just exactly same as the question.Nothing change with the code you provide above

Comment: i get the message Login worked,but my onlinestore.html got nothing change,it is just like the screenshot i provided.

Comment: And the second test I stated to use if the login returned ok?  `echo "This is working";exit();` - does this work on onlinestore.html?

Comment: where should i copy this to my onlinestore.html?
before echo $_SESSION['username']?

Comment: As I said in the answer, at the very top of the file. Just want to check the echo works ok. Then let me know if you get a white page with just "This is working" or not.

Comment: It's only show login worked,but the this is working is not shown

Comment: You really need to read all the advice given. I said here and in the other answer that `.html` files don't parse PHP by default. You need to either change your file extensions whenever you want PHP to work in them (eg change `onlinestore.html` to `onlinestore.php`) or use the other approach of making PHP work within html files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files#11312349

Comment: In fact, if the site is not live or too large already, and if you're going to be using PHP here and there (as you are starting to already), it might be worth considering changing all your files and internal links to .php.  Doing it now while you're developing the site is much better than having to attack this once it's live and too late to make it a simple job.

Answer (score 2):

In your `else` statement you haven't defined a `session_start()` like you did in your `if` statement.

And else, instead of checking the value of a $_SESSION and determining the value of it, you can use the following:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
//Do something if the session is not existing
}
```

Other options are storing variables in a `$_COOKIE` and then check if it `isset` or not(`if(isset($_COOKIE["username"]){}`)

I hope this has helped you out

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a lot of code missing.

Where is your login script?

First, you need a `<form>` with the input fields (login and password) and a submit button.

For example:

```
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='loginname'></input>
<input type='password' name='loginpassword'></input>
<input type='submit'>Submit</input>
</form>
```

Your login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Dont forget to check your variables
$loginname = $_POST["loginname"];
$password = $_POST["loginpassword"];
// Check the correct login (for example with a database)
if ($login_correct) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $loginname;
    $_SESSION["logged"] = true;
    header("index.html");
    exit;
else {
    $_SESSION["logged"] = false;
    header("registerform.html");
    exit;


   }
}
?>
```

In your index.html you can do:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['logged'] == true){ 
    echo $_SESSION["username"];
    echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
}
else {
    echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: i do have this part but it's quite long,so i just skip that part

Comment: show us the code where you set the session. I think the session is empty. You can check which session is set with `var_dump($_SESSION)`.

Comment: Maybe the `$myusername` is empty. Where you set this variable?

Comment: $myusername=$_POST["myusername"];
$mypassword=$_POST["mypassword"];

Comment: and the name attribute from the '<input>' elements is also set to `myusername` and `mypassword` ? (`<input type='text' name='myusername'></input>` and same for `mypassword`)

Comment: Have you also delete the space between `$_SESSION [` in `$_SESSION ['username']=$myusername;` ? Like: `$_SESSION['username']=$myusername;`

Comment: checked,there is no space between them

Answer (score 0):

If you want the username to be displayed instead like in the example you need to change your code for onlinestore.html to the following:

```
<li class='active' style='float:right;'>
  <?php 
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['logged']==true){ 
      echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>' + $_SESSION["username"] + ' (Logout)</span></a></li>';
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false) 
      echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your PHP should look something like that:

```
<?php 
session_start();
username = $_SESSION["username"]
if($_SESSION['logged'] == true) { 
    echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>' . username. 'Logout</span></a></li>';
    }
else {
    echo '<a href="registerform.html"><span>Login/Register</span></a></li>';
}
?>
```

Use either brackets in both if and else or use none. By the way you don't need an elseif if you're only checking a boolean. (there are only 2 possibilities)

Comment: This would not work because she/he did not properly call the variable `username` it should be `$username` and nor did he/she [properly end that line in this demo @JK9 and if you use it letter for letter, then it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="msg"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
<form type="submit">
   <input type="text" name="Email">
   <input type="password" name="Password">
   <button type="submit" name="Login">Login</button>
</form>
<?php
  require 'connection.php';
  if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
      $email = $_POST['Email'];
      $password = $_POST['Password'];

      $user = "SELECT username FROM table_name WHERE email = '".$email."' and password = '".$password."'";
      $user = mysqli_query($con, $user);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($user) > 0) {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user)) {
               $username = $row['username'];
         }
      } else {
                $msg = "Can't Log in";
      }
    }
     echo $username;
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't how to explain but when the login is successful I created the session variable. If the session variable is not in used it will echo the Login that will link to login page otherwise if session variable is being used it will print the username

code in process of logging in

```
        if($row['col_userName'] == $username AND $row['col_custPass'] = $password){
             $_SESSION['session_var_user'] = $username; // I created the session variable also don't forget to put the session_start(); at the top of your code
            echo "
                    <script> 
                      window.location.href = 'index.php';
                    </script>
                ";
            }else{echo "failed";}
```

code in navbar

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class = "justtextstyle" href="#">
                <?php 
                   if(!isset($_SESSION['session_variable']))
  // if(!isset($_SESSION['session_variable'])) checking if $_SESSION['session_variable' is in use; sorry idk to explain, it's just like that lol 
                   {
                       echo "<a class = 'justtextstyle' href='login.php'>Log In Here</a>";
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       echo "Hi," . $_SESSION['session_variable'];
                   }
               ?>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this instead, it worked for me.

```
<?php 
  if($_SESSION['username'] == true) { 
     echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<a href="login.php"><span>Login</span></a>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a reply, even if it is right, try to explain it a little bit.